# WHy the call is not going to the jQuery function in following scenario?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My HTML code is as follows:

```
<span class="c-bl-btn c-mail-btn-another"><input type="button" class="more send_email" name="" id="" value="Email Invoice" data="../modules/transactions/view_transactions.php?op=email_invoice&txn_no=1001&user_id=101"></span>

$('.send_email').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var ans=confirm("Are you sure to Email this invoice?");
      if(!ans) {
            return false;
      }

    var post_url = $(this).attr('href');    
    $.ajax({
        url: post_url,
        type : 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var status       = data.status;
            var dialog_title = "Email Invoice";
            var message      = data.msg; 

             if(status == 'success') {
                 var $dialog = $("<div class='ui-state-success'></div>")
                 .html("<p class='ui-state-error-success'>"+message+"</p>")
                 .dialog({
                     autoOpen: false,
                     modal:true,
                     title: dialog_title,
                     width: 500,                       
                     buttons:{
                         'OK': function() {
                             $(this).dialog('close');   

                         }                           
                     }

                 });                    
             } else {       
                 var $dialog = $("<div></div>")
                 .html("<p class='ui-state-error-text'>"+message+"</p>")
                 .dialog({
                     autoOpen: false,
                     modal:true,
                     title: dialog_title,
                     width: 500,                       
                     buttons:{
                         'OK': function() {
                             $(this).dialog('close');
                         }                             
                     }                            
                 });                         
             }  
              $dialog.dialog('open'); 
        }
    });
});
```

Also there is no error in the firebug console. I'm using jQuery 1.9. But If I call a javascript function it is getting a call. I tried a lot but didn't get the satisfactory solution. Can anyone help me out to give a call to the jQuery function? Thanks in advance.
If I use following code to call the javascript function it is getting called.

```
<span class="c-bl-btn c-mail-btn-another"><input type="button" class="more send_email" name="" id="" value="Email Invoice" data="$control_url}modules/transactions/view_transactions.php?op=email_invoice&txn_no={$user_transaction_details.transaction_no}&user_id={$user_id}" onclick="open_win()"></span>

function open_win()
{
var ans=confirm("Are you sure to Email this invoice?");
      if(!ans) {
            return false;
      }

}
```

Comment: what do you mean, your ajax call is not getting through or js function in not called ?

Comment: @Anand:The js function is not getting called.

Comment: There are also couple of other mistakes in your code. This function has to be invoked on click of a button, right ?

Comment: @Anand:If there are mistakes in the code then how javascript function is getting called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of other mistakes in your code which I noticed.

1. If you are calling this code on click of button which has class `"send_email" -   <input type="button" class="more send_email" name="" id="" value="Email Invoice" data="../modules/transactions/view_transactions.php?op=email_invoice&txn_no=1001&user_id=101">`

Here you see your input tag in not well formed and you have missed `"/"`

2 . If its a button(i.e `$(this)`) , you can not use `$(this).attr('href');`  . It's only true for a hyperlink.

3 . I see you have stored the post location in a `data` attribute. It should be `data-attributeName` instead.

so it should be `data-url = "../modules/transactions/view_transactions.php?op=email_invoice&txn_no=1001&user_id=101"`

and you can access it by following  `$(this).data("url")`

JSFiddle is currently down. I will try to make one fiddle when it will be up again

[JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/rUmXe/)

Comment: :Thanks for your answer. the jsFiddle is up now.

Comment: gone down again. I am trying to replicate your scenario

Comment: :I made the changes you suggested but still the jQuery function is not getting called.

Comment: Yes, those were additional changes. Those will not fix your current issue. I just saw some additonal mistake and posted it. I am trying to replicate it on JSFiddle right now

Comment: I was able to bind to button click event. I have removed ajax stuff, because your problem was the click event not getting bound